# Handle output that can either be an array or a single string

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have script which retrieves data from a web service in XML format. Certain elements can be there - or not - and can contain one or more sub elements. Therfore I retrieve the value with this:

`$uid = $changeRecord.newAttrs | Where{$_.name -eq 'uid'} | Select -ExpandProperty Values | select -Index 0`

This works fine. Mostly there is only one sub element in the `<values>` part of the answer and even if not, I am only interested in the first one. However, the last part `| select -Index 0` produces silent warnings into the Windows Event Log (see also [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/675793/powershell-script-generates-lots-of-warnings-in-windows-event-log) ) if there is only one element within `<values>`. Therefore I would like to get rid of the error.

So I am looking for a way to achieve the same behaviour without it throwings errors - and possible not just put try-catch around.

Thanks!

// Update: As discussed below, the answers presented so far do not solve the issue. The closest by now is

```
([array]($changeRecord.newAttrs | Where{$_.name -eq 'uid'} | Select -ExpandProperty Values))[0]
```

This, however, fails with an error if the array does not contain any elements. Any idea if this can be handled as well within one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found a solution which is probably fine for me:

```powershell
$valueArray = [array]($changeRecord.newAttrs | Where{$_.name -eq 'uid'} | Select -ExpandProperty Values)

if(($valueArray -ne $null) -and ($valueArray.Count -gt 0))
{
    $value = $valueArray.GetValue(0)
}
else
{
   $value = "null..."
}
```

I put the whole thing into an array first and then check if the array contains any elements. Only if so, I get the first value.

Thanks for everybodys help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this: `Select-Object -First 1` ?

```powershell
$uid = $changeRecord.newAttrs |
    Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'uid'} |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Values |
            Select-Object -First 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`Select -Index n` is only meant to be used on arrays as it will explicitly select from that index in the array. Therefore you will have issues when doing it on a single object. `Select -First n` will get you `n` number of objects off the pipeline.

All that said, when I am calling a command and the results may either be a single item or an array of items, I generally declare the variable as an array or cast the value as an array and then even if I get a single object back from the command it will be stored in an array. That way no matter what gets returned, I am treating it the same way. So in your case:

`$uid = [array]($changeRecord.newAttrs | Where{$_.name -eq 'uid'} | Select -ExpandProperty Values) | select -Index 0`

Comment: Funny, I prefer `Select-Object -First \ -Last 1` in situations when I need first\last object and not the `n`'s one, because it's more explicit: I don't like to treat those situations same way. When re-reading code it's stands up and I'm sure that I wanted exactly the first\last object and not the `n`'s one. Matter of taste :).

Comment: Turns out neither of your solutions solves the problem :( Message is still showing up. What I just tried and seems to work is `([array]($changeRecord.newAttrs | Where{$_.name -eq 'uid'} | Select -ExpandProperty Values))[0]` This however only works, if there is an element named `uid`. If not, and error will occur. Can I implement this within one line or would I need to declare the variable first and then check if the array contains any elements before accessing `[0]`? thx!